# Attribute herf is not a valid attribute of element 'a'

Tags: html, asp.net

all.

A HREF does not work. It's not even showing a finger/hand pointer.

I got a green line under href and target and it says:

href => Attribute herf is not a valid attribute of element 'a' 
target => Attribute is allowed only when href is present

What is wrong? The text "Get Lat&Long" supposed to be a hyperlink but it appears to be a text!

My code

```
<td class="auto-style27">
    <asp:Label ID="lblBusWebAdd0" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="#666666" Text="Latitude"></asp:Label>
    &nbsp;
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddBusLat" runat="server" Width="158px"></asp:TextBox> <a herf="http://www.gps-coordinates.net/" target="_blank">Get Lat&Long</a>
</td>
```

Thank you in advance~

Comment: As message says: attribute HERF is not valid attribute. On the other hand, 'href' is. :)

Comment: The error message says everything you need to know. Be careful with spelling. A HTML-Parser is not very tolerant with this.

Comment: Hahahahah :D I also noticed that right after posting. Was gonna delete it but my crappy internet went down~ but anyway, the answer is right so placing a vote~ Thanks all~

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You wrote in your code

```
<a herf="
```

however, this is correct:

```
<a href="
```

Spelling matters.

Comment: Hahahahah :D I also noticed that right after posting. Was gonna delete it but my crappy internet went down~ but anyway, the answer is right so placing a vote~ Thanks all~